# intra-rater reliability and assessment error - which ICC type to use? singular rater

Tags: intraclass-correlation

I'm trying to figure out which ICC type to use to calculate MY measurement error using a particular  assessment tool:

background and data:

PhD feasibility phase only.

10 pairs of videos of people doing every day tasks. Videos were  scored 3 times to assess measurement error. Videos were randomly scored purposely to reduce the learning effect.

There is one rater (me).

Each pair of tasks = one complete assessment per person.

Linear data from an assessment that yields two scales, (raw scores go into software that uses rasch analysis,  transforming data into logits). Raw scores (36 skills scored either 1,2,3 or 4) could be used but not alone, to supplement is OK.

I have limited time to collect data, so 10 is all I can do. I'm looking for something simple, suitable and accurate. I am happy to do 2 or 3 different stats to get an accurate measurement of my scoring consistency.

I've read intra-rater reliability studies that are similar, but only retest once, (rather than twice, as I have), using ICC 1 and ICC 1,2, also studies with several raters and video scoring 5 times which used ICC fixed 3.1 version.

Answers and advice gratefully received.